# Can I sell my software if I use external open source software?

Tags: javascript, jquery, open-source, licensing

In the [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)/[HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) world all code can be seen by the user (not complicated), so the question is if I use libraries such as

- jQuery MIT
- Require MIT/new BSD
- Three.js MIT
- CodeMirro MIT
- Yeoman BSD
- CoffeeScript MIT
- Box2dweb zlib
- LDT GPL v3/MIT
- GNU License

  1. Can I my sell/rent my software that I created using these tools, for example, for a monthly fee of X.X amount?
  2. Can a user of my software use one or many of the above open software in his/her project which was created using my software and would be distributed under my licenses?

I'm still getting my head around the licenses so an easy-to-follow explanation would be great. I's an online tool and the user would need to pay to use and can export that would include the library's above.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: You'd have to read up on each license, but most of the licenses you cite are very liberal and don't have issues with selling them or modifying them (MIT, BSD).  As for the others: non-lawyer summary is that the GPL/GNU License and the like only cover modifications to the software itself - if you add something to LDT, you have to share it with everyone else, but you can *use* LDT without it affecting your ownership of your code.

[OpenSource.org](http://opensource.org/faq) has a good FAQ (and list of licenses), particularly their explanation of [copyleft](http://opensource.org/faq#copyleft), which describes the GPL and similar:

> Copyleft provisions apply only to actual derivatives, that is, cases where an existing copylefted work was modified. Merely distributing a copyleft work alongside a non-copyleft work does not cause the latter to fall under the copyleft terms.

Including a Javascript library from your code most certainly falls under "distributing alongside", so the only thing you have to worry about is if you add things to/modify the licensed code itself, and even then the only thing you have to share back is your modifications.

And in all these cases: you can [sell it no matter what](http://opensource.org/faq#commercial).

Of course, if software is not under a free license and instead has some sort of other license attached to it (an example would be the excellent [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)) you'll have to abide by the terms of that license, and purchase whatever licenses are required.